# Google Apps Script to highlight multiple choice

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs, highlight

I'm trying to make a Google Apps Script that will highlight multiple choice answers in a Google Doc. Here's an example question:

```
Question....blah blah blah.
a. Answer 1
b. Answer 2
c. Answer 3
d. Answer 4
e. Answer 5
```

And here's what I've got so far for a script:

```
function highlight() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nP6ra0zIMI3OB-zsTMbFybO2e7ajoYgQi8doDcurGew/edit?usp=sharing');
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#E3E65B';
  var text = doc.editAsText();
  var result = text.findText(/^(a|b|c|d|e)\..*/gm).getElement();
   for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
   result[i].setAttributes(style);
   }
}
```

But it just gives me "Cannot call method "getElement" of null".

Answer (score 0):

You are not expecting a no matched result. Try this instead.

```
function highlight() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nP6ra0zIMI3OB-zsTMbFybO2e7ajoYgQi8doDcurGew/edit?usp=sharing');
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#E3E65B';
  var text = doc.editAsText();
      if(text.findText(/^(a|b|c|d|e)\. Answer [0-9]+$/gm) !== "undefined")
      {   
         var result = text.findText(/^(a|b|c|d|e)\. Answer [0-9]+$/gm)).getElement();
         for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
         {
           result[i].setAttributes(style);
         }
      } 
      else 
      {
        //Do whatever. There is no element matched
      }
}
```

On the other hand, the regex `/^(a|b|c|d|e)\..*/gm` means:

Begins with `a OR b OR c OR d OR e`, `.`, any character 0 or more times (`.*`). `g` flag means that will continue searching after the first match. The `m` flag means that `$` and `^` can match the beginning of a line and the end of a line respectively.

So it will match something like this: `a.anything`, `b.66/qQ-.r...`, etc.

If you want to match something like `a. Answer 1`, you should use:

`/^(a|b|c|d|e)\.\s.+\s[0-9]+$/gm`

If it is going to be always `Answer` you could use:

`/^(a|b|c|d|e)\.\sAnswer\s[0-9]+$/gm`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But the problem I was trying to get at is that I think there's something wrong with how I'm using the `var result = text.findText(/^(a|b|c|d|e)\..*/gm).getElement();` line. I don't think I properly understand either the regex part or the `.findText` command

Comment: Ok, I want it to match all the answers (`a. Answer 1`, `b. Answer 2`, etc) so I edited the regex to be `/^(a|b|c|d|e)\.\s.*/gm` so that the space in between the period and answer text also matches (don't know if the `\s` is needed though with the `.*` ). Also, I edited the code to match what you suggested (with the if statement) and it still gives me the same error (the line it errors at is `var result = text.findText(/^(a|b|c|d|e)\..*/gm).getElement();` ).

Comment: Try removing the ^ symbol

Comment: By the way, are you using Mootools? If not, what is `getElement()` function? Maybe would work if you remove it.

Comment: Still didn't work. I don't know what Mootools is, but here's where I got the `getElement()` function: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/search-result#getElement()

Comment: Sorry! I didn't see `google apps` tag. Well, after seeing google apps documentation, my last guess is updated. Try now.

Comment: Still having issues. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/nI8uRCB.png?1 is that any different from what you have?