# Use script to change style for multiple words

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to use the script to modify the style of different words in my google document. Since many words will have the same style I want to group them in an array. Other words need their own individual style. I built some code for that, but it does not work so far. The following error appears:

> TypeError: Cannot find function findText in object Description:. (line 19, file "Code")

(this line ==> `textLocation = words[w].findText(textToHighlight);`). The script is supposed to be triggered by Zapier through a webhook.

```
function doGet() {
  var docid = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  var doc  = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
  var words = ['Description:','Who can help you:']
  var textToHighlight = words[w];
  var highlightStyle = {};
  highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#000000';
  highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = '16';
  highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = 'true';
  var textToHighlight2 = 'Hello';
  var highlightStyle2 = {};
  highlightStyle2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#FFC000';
  var paras = doc.getParagraphs();
  var textLocation = {};
  var i;
  var w;

  for (w=0; w<words.length; ++w) {
    textLocation = words[w].findText(textToHighlight);
    if (textLocation != null && textLocation.getStartOffset() != -1) {
      textLocation.getElement().setAttributes(textLocation.getStartOffset(),textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive(), highlightStyle);
  for (i=0; i<paras.length; ++i) {
  textLocation = paras[i].findText(textToHighlight2);
if (textLocation != null && textLocation.getStartOffset() != -1) {
      textLocation.getElement().setAttributes(textLocation.getStartOffset(),t.extLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive(), highlightStyle2);
      }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear as the question didn't mention if the script is an standalone or a bounded project also it didn't describe how the script works an where do you get stuck.

Comment: Please add that to the question and edit the question wording accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because findText isn't a method of Object String. It could be used on Class Body or Class Text

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern

Related Q/A

- [Google Apps Script to highlight multiple choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19775456/1595451)
- [apps script findText for docs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43741973/1595451)

Comment: "...regular expression features are not fully supported, such as capture groups..." so there is no way of doing it with my current approach? Sorry for being so clueless.